# How to check index exist or not in my array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have two arrays
one show all the quiz. another one shows the all taken quiz. now I like o show this for each array that where all quiz list neet to show but match the done quiz table, if available it will return status true. I am using array_key_exist but its showing error.

```
$getquizId = [
            'id' => '',
            'title' => '',
            'status' => ''
        ];
        $allquizId = [];


        $totalQuiz = Quize::where('course_id', $course_id)->with('resources')->get();

        $doneQuiz =  QuizProgress::where('user_id', $user_id)->where('course_id', $course_id)->with('course')->get();
        $progress = (count($doneQuiz) / count($totalQuiz)) * 100;

        foreach ($totalQuiz as $key => $value) {
            $getquizId = [
                'id' => $value->id,
                'title' => $value->title,
                'status' => (array_key_exists($key, $doneQuiz) ? ($value->id == $doneQuiz[$key]['id'] ? true : false) : false)
            ];
            // if (array_key_exists($key, $doneQuiz)) {

            //  ($value->id == $doneQuiz[$key]['quiz_id'] ? $getquizId['status'] = 'true' : $getquizId['status'] = 'false'); 
            // }

            array_push($allquizId, $getquizId);
        }



        return $allquizId;
```

In here `(array_key_exists($key, $doneQuiz) ? ($value->id == $doneQuiz[$key]['id'] ? true : false) : false)` I need to check the array key exist o not.

I want to show the array like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Digital Marketing",
        "status": true
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "Personal Leadership",
        "status": false
    }
]
```

Comment: Please reference your array, so, other person can know what's input and what's output

Comment: updated my code

Comment: Can you please post your array and what out put you want??

Comment: _"but its showing error"_ - Share the error message. Also, nesting multiple ternary operations is a good way to make your code hard to read and maintain.

Comment: `[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Digital Marketing",
        "status": true
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "Personal Leadership",
        "status": false
    }
]`

Comment: if I use  `$getquizId = [
    'id' => $value->id,
    'title' => $value->title,
    'status' => ($value->id == $doneQuiz[$key]['id'] ? true : false)
   ];` 
"Undefined offset: 1"`

Comment: What is value in `$totalQuiz`? You must have to give reference of your input and output array

Comment: use just want to update the status of current quiz from the QuizProgress right ?

Comment: yes right, There is two table and return two different array set, need to match this array. and need to update the `$getquizId['status] = true` if match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the id of the quiz which is done, and then check the array with in_array
But I would suggest you make the proper relationship

```
$doneQuiz =  QuizProgress::where('user_id', $user_id)->where('course_id', $course_id)->with('course')->pluck('quiz_id')->toArray();

$getquizId = [
    'id' => $value->id,
    'title' => $value->title,
    'status' => in_array($value->id, $doneQuiz) ? true : false
];
```

Comment: done quiz also a set of array collection `[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "user_id": 7,
        "quiz_id": 4,
        "course_id": 3,
        "complete": "2018-06-07 02:38:14",
        "course": {
            "id": 3,
            "segment_id": null,
            "title": "Digital Marketing",
            "smc": "",
            "ytd": "PL1pf33qWCkmjlwVA4BE2JcZsM3r5vG6_j"
        }
    }
]`

Comment: i need to match `$value->id` with `$doneQuiz[$key]['quiz_id']` :(

Comment: do you have quiz_id in QuizProgress ?

Comment: then get the quiz_id from QuizProgress model check the updated answer

Comment: i did, but when no match key it show unndeifine index 1, :(

Answer (score 0):

Dear always try to do some proper code.

```
$bool = false;
if(isset($doneQuiz[$key]['id']) && $value->id === $doneQuiz[$key]['id'] )
    $bool = true;
```

put above code before `$getquizId` array and add $bool variable in value of status.

Note: check the `$doneQuiz` getting in array format.

Comment: thank you,but if the $key value dont exit in $doneQuiz it shhow error :(